# journalctl prints the entire system log when following

Tags: centos, systemd, journalctl

```
[root@utility ~]# uname -rv
2.6.32-042stab093.5 #1 SMP Wed Sep 10 17:39:49 MSK 2014

[root@utility ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

[root@utility ~]# journalctl --version
systemd 208
+PAM +LIBWRAP +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ
```

I'm having a rather odd issue when walking my syslogs through `journalctl`. In context, I'm trying to actively follow the entire system log to try and troubleshoot an issue with OpenDKIM but I'm making progress in that area.

Essentially, when I run `journalctl -f` I am presented with the last few lines of the log and the terminal waits for more data to be logged and processed. With this process open in one SSH session, I send a test message from a different session on the same server (both under the root user).

Once I execute the test message, the program dumps content into the system log. I briefly see the content dumped before the `journalctl` process circles back around and writes out the entire system log to the console from as far back as the logs go all the way to what was just written to the log. Needless to say, this isn't very helpful when you have to wait for months worth of syslogs to be pushed through your SSH session before you can see what the test program wrote to the log.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is occurring? I'm embarrassed to say I don't even know where to start, but my Google-Fu has revealed no other instances of such an issue.

> Hell, maybe my luck with search engines has finally come to a bitter end...

TL;DR: `journalctl -f` reads out the entire system log rather than just tailing it.

Comment: Stop using that OpenVZ-based VPS. Its kernel is too old to run modern systemd reliably.

Comment: PITA, I know, but I prefer it to be a functional PITA until I have the opportunity to migrate it.